# How to pass data to different controller in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create factory for the restful services.

I need to make service calls. First call's data will be used to get the second calls data.
My problem is I don't know how to transfer data from one controller to another controller.

Is there a better way to do my codes?

Here are my codes...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

//getting init data via service
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
  var myService = {
    async: function() {     
      var promise = $http.get('test/test.json').then(function (response) {

        return response.data;
      });
       return promise;
    }
  };
  return myService;
});


//retrieve data 
app.controller('testCtrl', function(myService, $scope, $http) {
   myService.async().then(function(data) {
       $scope.data = data
       //using retrieve data to get another piece of data
       vay first = data[0].employee[0];
   })    

   $http({
        url: "test?" + first +'.json',
        method: "GET",
        }).success(function(secondData) {
           $scope.secondData=secondData  //How do I pass data to my secondCtrl?
        })
})


app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {
   // I need to be able to get the secondData from testCtrl.
   console.log($scope.secondData)
})
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you store the data as an object in the service itself, then both controllers depend on the service and have access to the data.  Like this:

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
    var that = this;
    var myService = function($http) {
        this.set = function(url) {     
             var promise = $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
                that.data = promise.data;


        });
           return promise;
        }
    };
    return new myService($http);
});
```

Then your controller sets and gets the data in the way

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function(myService, $scope, $http) {
   myService.set('someurl').then(function() {
       $scope.data = myservice.data;
       //using retrieve data to get another piece of data
       vay first = data[0].employee[0];

       myservice.set('someOtherUrl?data='+first);
}) 



app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, myservice) {
    //the data object on the myservice function has been changed on the first controller and we can reasonably expect the data we need.  If these 2 controllers coexist in the same space and time we can wrap this in a $watch service
    console.log(myservice.data)
});
```

$watch service example

```
app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope, $watch, myservice) {
    $watch('myservice.data', function(newval, oldval) {
        console.log(newval);
    }, true)
    //I will only log the newvalue of myservice.data when the data has changed.  the last true argument is a neccesity so that angular will compare the values within the object
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either extend 'myService' to contain the response data, using it in both controllers, or you could create another service for sharing data between them.

Both solutions would look similar, but here is what the second option (new service) might look like:

**Factory**

```
.factory('SharedService', function(){
    var shared = {
      data: ''
    }
    return shared;
})
```

This factory could act as just a place to store some data. In fact, if all you'd like to do is share data, you could just use a [value provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#value-recipe). But a factory you could later extend with a more complex data structure and methods.

In your controllers, just inject the service and, optionally, set it to a scope variable:

**Controller 1**

```
.controller('FirstController', function($scope, SharedService){
    $scope.shared = SharedService;
    $scope.shared.data = 'foo';
})
```

`$scope.shared` now references the service object. If you were to do the same in the other controller, they could both read/write to that same object:

**Controller 2**

```
.controller('SecondController', function($scope, SharedService){
    $scope.shared = SharedService;
    console.log($scope.shared.data); // 'foo' if called after first ctrl set it
})
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0byckXO0co2OpcMZ9Nrl?p=preview)